# Should I include translation correctness in functional testing?

Tags: django, testing, translation

We build a multi-language website. In the code, we mark English strings for translation, but the default language is our native language (Hungarian).

Should I set the default language for testing to English or Hungarian?

- If I set it to English, the tests will be closer to the code, as the test writer only need to look at the code to write the tests.
- If I set it to Hungarian, the tests will be more thorough, because they can also spot translation mistakes, missing translations, etc. But in this case, they would be more tied to the user interface, not the code. I'm not sure if this is a pro or con.

What are other advantages/disadvantages?
Has anyone experience with this?

Comment: If you were writing a novel, writing it in English exponentially increases the number of your novel's potential readers. It holds true that in your native language whatever you express shall be more sharp and accurate. You should bear in mind, however, that a good translator is also an artist!

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if your whole team speak Hungarian or not, but you should always writing code in English since every (decent) programmer know this language and neither you nor the other person will have problems with translation and understanding the code (at least not at the language-layer).

You never know, maybe in next year other team/company will take your project over ? Will you translate then the test to English ? Sounds like a waste of time.